# How to perform a sequential query in GatsyJS's pageQuery?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Common graphql question here, but i cant find the answer on how to do this in Gatsby.

I need to fetch data for a single page from different data sources, CMS A and CMS B). The we need to fetch from CMS B depends on the contentIDs from CMS A.

My pageQuery is currently as following:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    homePage {
      title
      contentIdsCmsB  <---- this yields a list of ids to query in CMS B
    }
  }
`
```

Is there any way to instruct Gatsby to query CMS B's graphql API? I know Apollo Client has something like 'compose' to do these type of things but I cannot find anything similar for gatsby.

Comment: with Gatsby currently, you can't do this via graphql query -- but I think it's possible to resolve these nested id yourself in [createResolvers](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-03-18-releasing-new-schema-customization/#createresolvers)